# How to set different keyboard layout language for different windows?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, language

How to change keyboard layout in windows 8.1?
My windows 7 had a very nice feature by which, for each window I could change keyboard layout.
Let's say, my Skype in English, my IE in Spanish and my MS word in Catalan.
But, I don't have this feature in my new windows 8.1; **how can activate this?**

Note: I didn't activate such feature in my Win 7 and it seemed to be its default feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycle through installed keyboard languages with Alt+Shift and check

> Let me set a different input method for each app window

[image]